Как оптимально найти все точки, которые попадут в радиус при движении из точки А в точку Б?
Есть точка А=0 и точка Б=1000, и есть радиус С=3.
Так же есть красные точки. Все на этом рисунке Vector3, кроме разумеется радиуса.
Как я могу оптимально получить все красные точки, которые попадут в радиус С при движении этого радиуса в точку Б?
Есть вариант в лоб - это в цикле for от i=0 до i<=1000 на каждой итерации вычислять дистацию i до красных точек, а потом проверять попадает ли она в радиус, но это как мне кажется неоптимально...
Есть какой-нибудь математический подход с минимальным числом итераций?


Эээ, нарисовать две линии, смещённые перпендикулярно AB на радиус в одну сторону и в другую и проверять каждую красную точку, попадает ли она между этими двумя линиями? Самих то красных точек сколько, меньше 1000? Если сильно меньше, то так должно быть выгодно. Проверка попадания вроде к простой какой-то формуле должна свестись.

Решение, предложенное в вопросе, оптимально. Есть тысяча несвязанных друг с другом точек. Единственный способ проверить что они близко к отрезку - проверить каждую отдельно.

От каждой точки нормаль к отрезку и смотреть длину нормали. Если больше радиуса, не попадает, если меньше, попадает. Ну и отдельно для тех точек, у которых нормаль не пересекается с отрезком проверить расстояние до ближайшего конца отрезка (крайние положения).

Нужно узнать точки в каждом положении (дискретном) кружка или просто все точки, которые будут заметены? Во втором случае итерации не нужны, просто посчитать расстояния от точек набора до отрезка.

Если отказаться от скруглений на концах отрезка, то можно сделать на линейных неравенствах (чтобы не считать расстояние). Вот интерактивная модель в desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ux9imdsejb?lang=ru В целом, можно проверять неравенства по очереди так, чтобы на проверку каждым следующим неравенством попадали только точки, прошедшие проверку всеми предыдущими. Конечно, скругления тоже можно добавить, но тогда неравенства уже будут второго порядка и придется чуть больше посчитать)

@Стас Ух ты, прикольная штука этот desmos, что только не придумают.

Можно проверить 2 окружности (начало и конец) и 1 прямоугольник  на поглощение указанных точек

Находим нормализованный направляющий вектор (в шарпе есть готовый метод Vector3D.Normalize)
Len = (B-A).Magnitude
uAB = (B-A) / Len

Для каждой точки P из набора считаем квадрат расстояния до отрезка, используя скалярное произведение (Vector3D.DotProduct), и сравниваем с квадратом радиуса.
F = Clamp(uAB.dot.(P-A), 0, Len)
D = A + uAB*F
G = P - D
SquaredDist = G.dot.G

F - вспомогательная величина для нахождения проекции точки P на прямую, содержащую отрезок AB, численно она равна знаковому расстоянию от A до D (проекции P).
Для точек, проекция которых попадает вне отрезка, находим расстояние от соответствующего конца отрезка. Если же нужно учитывать только цилиндр, а не капсулу с полукруглыми крышечками (точки типа P1 на рисунке), то F меньше нуля и больше Len следует игнорировать.

Каждая точка проверяется только один раз
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector3D A = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
            Vector3D B = new Vector3D(6, 0, 0);
            Vector3D AB = B - A;
            double Len = AB.Length;
            AB.Normalize();
            double R = 2.0;
            double RSq = R * R;
            double F;
            Vector3D C = new Vector3D();
            Vector3D G = new Vector3D();
            Vector3D[] P = new Vector3D[4];
            P[0] = new Vector3D(-1, -1, 0);
            P[1] = new Vector3D(2, 1, 1);
            P[2] = new Vector3D(5, 2, 2);
            P[3] = new Vector3D(8, 2, 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                C = P[i] - A;
                F = Vector3D.DotProduct(C, AB);
                F = Math.Min(Math.Max(F, 0), Len);    //Math.Clamp
                G = C - F * AB;
                if (G.LengthSquared <= RSq)
                    Console.WriteLine(P[i].X + " " + P[i].Y + " " + P[i].Z + " близко");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(P[i].X + " " + P[i].Y + " " + P[i].Z + " далеко");

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

Вывод:
-1 -1 0 близко
2 1 1 близко
5 2 2 далеко
8 2 2 далеко


Для полноты:
Кроме того, в зависимости от реальных условий задачи, может понадобиться грубо отфильтровывать те точки, которые ни за что не попадут в нужную окрестность. Например, если рабочее пространство большое, набор точек велик и не меняется, а отрезки разные (пример - перелеты космического корабля между звездами), то стоит построить некую структуру данных для деления пространства на области (space partition) - kd-tree, например. В простейшем случае - равные кубики, и каждом кубику соотнести точки, принадлежащие ему. Для очередного отрезка находим кубики, которые он пересекает и ближайшие в пределах радиуса. Таких кубиков может быть, например, всего сотая или тысячная доля от всего пространства, и проверяются только точки, находящиеся в этих кубиках.

А что значат точки между G.dot.G?

Так скалярное произведение обозначают. В шарпе будет Vector3D.DotProduct(G, G)

А можете рядом снизу написать, как все целиком будет выглядеть в шаровой реализации от начала и до конца?

Добавил пример работы

А "близко" - значит, что попадает под заданый радиус?

Да, именно так.

А какую литературу почитать или статьи почитать, чтобы вникнуть в происходящее?)

А что есть C, F и G? Я прост в коде понятные переменые задать хочу

Векторы G и С на картинке же нарисованы. F - длина проекции от A вдоль вектора AB

Спасибо. Подскажите, а не будет ложноположительных результатов за пределами отрезка АБ вот так вот https://ibb.co/dm7GvFw

Для точек, проекция которых лежит за пределами отрезка, считается расстояние не до проекции, а до ближайшего конца отрезка. Если оно меньше заданного - точка подходит. Если такие точки вообще не нужны - см. абзац над картинкой

Оффтопик код без var, читать легко и приятно

Можно, пожалуйста, вашу формулу самого движения и вычисления?
Математический подход это, как, кстати, уже упомянул @CrazyElf, вам нужно взять верхнюю точку вашего радиуса в начальной позиции и провести прямую к верхней точке этого же радиуса в конечной позиции. Аналогично сделать с нижней точкой радиуса.
Следующий шаг это перебор всех точек по критерию, если координата точки является решением уравнения нахождения точки между двух отрезков. Если пропустить много математики, возьмём первый отрезок A с координатами xA и yA, и аналогичную прямую B с координатами концов xB и yB, искомая точка P[xP, yP]. xP должна быть удовлетворять условие xA < xP < xB, если опустить факт, что прямые могут быть направлены в другую сторону (xA > xB). Аналогичное условие будет для координаты y. Условие для цикла будет примерно следующее:
foreach (var point in points)
{
    if ((a.X < point.X && point.X < b.X) &&
        (a.Y < point.Y && point.Y < b.Y))
        {
            // Точка между отрезками
        }
}


Не верхнюю точку радиуса, а перпендикулярно вектору AB нужно в одну сторону и в другую отойти на радиус от точек A и B и нарисовать там прямые. Минус не мой.

Минус мой. Ответ совсем неверный.

@MBo а, да, ещё скругления на концах, короче проще действительно расстояния посчитать, прямые не проводить, хотя чтобы сообразить что происходит эти отрезки могут быть полезны
